# Can't execute the Install manager file

Tags: java, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am trying to re-install Tizen Wearable IDE, the problem is when I execute the binary file "tizen-wearable-sdk-2.2.150_ubuntu64.bin" I got this message:

OpenJDK is not supported. Try again with Oracle JDK.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

OpenJDK which is the default java on Ubuntu is not supported by the install manager.

You should use Oracle java instead, I usually use the method described here to install it:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html